# Is it illegal or just unethical to resubmit the same grant form

Tags: ethics

Three years ago I wrote a grant for my current employer. This was a federal grant that was submitted and awarded to my current employer. I recently learned it is time to apply for the grant again. Instead of them re-writing the grant, they used the exact same information (word for word), removed my name and added their names.  Is this okay?

Comment: Did the company pay you for the time you spent writing it?

Comment: Considered "other duties as assigned per job description" and I am salary.

Comment: I think the question was did you do this as part of your job, which you answered "yes" - so, you did get paid for it. It's their grant proposal, not yours, per se, I think was the gist of asking that question.

Comment: @poloholeset yeah that’s what I was getting at. You can’t expect to have every piece of work you do for a company permanently attributed to you. The reward is the income.

Comment: I understand.  I guess what I meant to say is that I am not the company grant writer, that is not in my job description, or title, etc.. This was given as an additional task per the standard "other duties as assigned".  I worked after standard work hours writing this grant because I had my actual job to do.  But, I am exempt so there was no overtime, etc. just my regular salary.

Comment: I don't see how any of that is relevant, illegal, or unethical. Is the company committing fraud? It doesn't sound like it. The grant is theirs, not yours. It hardly seems relevant to me who wrote it and whether it was written "on hours" or "off".

Comment: You got paid, and after this people will stop coming to you with questions about it so you can get on with the rest of your work. I'd consider that a win-win, unless you want to get into having grant writing be a documented part of your job. If the latter, it's still at least a single win, but you may want to double-check to see if they'll support your claim that you wrote the original on your resume.

Comment: Are you sating that you wrote the grant ***application***? Or that you were, 3 years ago, working with the organization that awarded them the grant? " I find "I wrote  a grant" to be ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure why all the down votes.  Would this be equivalent to a movie studio hiring me to write a script, then crediting someone else at the end of the movie?  I write engineering reports for my employer.  I would think it would be weird/wrong for them to replace my name on all the reports after I retire.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere:  Thank you for pointing out my mistake.  I've never thought about the distinction between different types of authorship.  I did a little Googling and I guess this grant form would be considered a "work for hire" and the copyright would belong to the employer?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire

Answer (score 11):

Illegal? **No.**

Unethical? **Not that either.**

Is this okay? **Yep, this one.**

You carried out the writing of the grant proposal during the course of your employment (whether you did extra hours or not is largely irrelevant) so it's *their* grant proposal now.

Honestly I'd be taking this as a compliment - clearly they think your proposal was of decent quality since they are re-using it. Updating the names is an administrative convenience (presumably the people who are now named are the ones dealing with the grant application process this time around).